# Errors when using type variables in function invocation

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to understand [type variables for funcitons](http://2ality.com/2018/04/type-notation-typescript.html#type-variables-for-functions). The example uses only one but I'm trying to extend it to two. Various inputs produce outputs I don't understand.

```
function id<T, U>(arg1, arg2: U): U{ // error 1 below
  // return arg2 + arg2; // when uncommented, error 2 below 
  return arg2 * 2
      // ^--^ error 3 below
//^-------------^ error 4 below
}

var result = id<string, number>('lorem', 10)
```

*Error 1*

> `Parameter 'arg1' implicitly has an 'any' type.`

*Error 2*

> `error Operator '+' cannot be applied to types 'U' and 'U'.`

*Error 3*

> `The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.`

*Error 4*

> `Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'U'.`

I am confused in a couple of areas, so please feel free to suggest if these should be separate questions:

1: Doesn't specifying argument types with `<string, number>` register to the called function that these are the types for supplied arguments. Why do these need does `: T` need to be given again in the parameter list?

2: `U` here should just be a number, why can't I add it?

3: I don't understand what this error is really driving at.

4: This works if I simply return `arg2` without the multiplication. I don't understand why I cannot return a number here.

Comment: 1. You don't specify a type for arg1, so it implicitly has any. 2. The plus operator is not generic over all possible inputs, so no dice. 3. `U` in the function definition can be *anything*, so same as #2. 4. Type variables are not *parameters to the function*, they are preserved from the *types* of the parameters you pass. You seem to be confused on how generics work: this line `id<string, number>('lorem', 10)` does not assign string to `T` and number to `U`.

Answer (score 1):

The first error tells you, that you should always add a type to a parameter. `arg1` is currently untyped.

The other errors tell you:

You can only add up (`+`) numbers and strings, not everything (objects for example). Thats why you have to narrow down the generic U to be either a string or a number.

You can only multiply numbers (`*`) (and BigInts).

The main point here is: The function has to work without problems in every possible case.

Comment: So in that case, `<string, number>` seems not to be doing what I thought it was, ie registering with the called function that I am passing it a `string` and a `number`, otherwise it would know that `arg2` can be multiplied with `*`. No?

Comment: Right. Take `id<null, {}>(null, { what: "?" })` for example ... following your logic, that should work (it doesn't).

Comment: So what does the `<string, number>` even get you?

Comment: Nothing, as typescript does infer the types. `function id<U>(v: U) { return v; }` is a better example `id(12)` will evaluate to type number. `id("test") * 2` would however fail as you can't multiply strings.

Comment: I see. I guess I also don't see the value of saying the function will return type `U` with `:U`, like in the 2ality example. Is it correct to say that it will only ever work if you return the passed argument unmodified?

Comment: No, Typescript can and will infer a lot. Specifying the return type makes sense if you have a large function, and it is n't obvious what it returns (then you just have to look at the header)

Comment: It makes sense to specify what kind of data you are returning, but I'm asking specifically about saying returning the type variable, basically the only thing that will satisify that particular return assertion with certainty will be the argument itself.

Comment: Yes right, the `id(arg: U): U` is a very contrived example.

Answer (score 0):

> 1: Doesn't specifying argument types with  register to
>   the called function that these are the types for supplied arguments.
>   Why do these need does : T need to be given again in the parameter
>   list?

The types in the function declaration don't map 1:1 with its parameters. If you want `arg1` to be of type `U`, you'll need to specify it.

> 2: U here should just be a number, why can't I add it?
>
> 3: I don't understand what this error is really driving at.
>
> 4: This works if I simply return arg2 without the multiplication. I
>   don't understand why I cannot return a number here.

Just need to tell TypeScript that `U` is a number: `<T, U extends number>`.

Also to note, the compiler can figure out the return type of your function in this case, so you can omit it. I think you want to end up somewhere like this:

```
function id<T, U extends number>(arg1: T, arg2: U) {
 return arg2 * 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. TypeScript is not JS. It is more strict, generally.
2. TypeScript does not have convention over configuration and you can 3 and more arguments. so you should explicitly set argument type;
3. There is no operator overloading syntax support in TS (like we have in C#). 
   Type argument constraints supported, though. So you can write

```
function id<T, U extends SomeClass>(...)
```

to use SomeClass props inside you func. And you can write "U extends number" to support add/subtract operations. Also you can use valueOf function of your object (used under the hood by js) and cast arg2 to 'any' (no need to use valueOf if your argument is a number already):

```
    // valid TS code:

    var obj = {
        foo: 123,
        valueOf: function(){return this.foo;}
    };

    console.log((obj as any) + 1); //will be 124

    // workaround - using '+' sign (valueOf used as well)

    console.log(+obj + 1); //will be 124
```

4. If you want to work with numbers - just work with numbers, or use your specific API (use interfaces)